# iOS Application Design Issue and associated UIImagePickerController Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a TabBar which has 4 items. All the 4 items respond to individual UIViewControllers. For example there is a item, which displays a screen to the user to get a photograph and upload it to a site. Now this UIViewController (postAppViewController) gets called from the AppDelegate like the following:

```
[tabItemsViewControllers addObject: [[ PostPageViewController alloc] initWithPost]];
```

where initWithPost defines the TabBar in described above.

Now postAppViewController calls a separate UIView (postAppView) from loadView. Then postAppView calls in one UINavigationController and one UITableViewController (postTableViewController).

Is this good design? I guess not because I am running into the following:

postTableViewController displays a Button which when clicked kicks in a UIImagePickerController (kicker) which then is presented to the user by calling the following:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

What I am seeing is that the tabbar exists and comes over the Camera/Image Library presentModalViewController.

Can you point out if I am going wrong with design or what else I can do to make sure the tabBar problem gets solved. Let me know if I am not being very clear in here.

Many Thanks.
AB

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way I handle the tabbar/nav controller stuff is that in my app delegate, I construct all of the view controllers.  In there I also construct the nav controller(s).  When I add the view controllers to the tab bar (setViewControllers:), I set the nav controller(s).  I have a few apps where some of the tabs have nav controllers and some don't and this scheme seems to work out pretty well.  I don't have the code in front of me though to give you a specific example. I will say that doing it this way, I never see the problems you run into and I use the camera/library picker a lot along with other modal view controllers.  Is that at all clear?

Comment: Thanks Merky, it would be simpler to do it from the App Delegate itself as you don't have to deal with multiple Classes. Your approach is simpler and ofcourse will work for me as well, but I right now want to organize the code in a better way hence the attempt to use multiple classes and hierarchical Views/ViewControllers. Will fall back to doing it from the App Delegate or do everything from one Class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Present the modal view controller from the UITabBarController instead of the associated UIViewController

`[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]`

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to figure out how to call the tabBarController which is a sub-class of the parentViewController of the class I am trying to present the imagepicker from.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your tip. The following works fine for me.

        `TestAppDelegate *testAppDelegate = (TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`
        `[testAppDelegate.bottomTabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`